# Replace FormsIdentity with WindowsIdentity in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I have an app running on a Windows Phone 8.1 device which accesses a backend build on ASP.NET MVC WebAPI. The authentication is done with FormsAuthentication because WindowsAuthentication is not possible in this setup. I could make it run: The user enters her credentials in a custom login form on the phone and on the server side the credentials get validated against Active Directory. After that the client gets an AuthenticationToken.

This snippet is from the LoginController:

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, password))
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
else
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

And this snippet shows the configuration of the authentication in the Web.Config:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms" />
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
  <membership defaultProvider="MembershipADProvider">
    <providers>
      <add name="MembershipADProvider" 
           type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
           connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"/>
    </providers>
  </membership>
</system.web>
```

My problem is that the FormsIdentity exposes only the username. But the backend expects a WindowsIdentity which contains the SID of the AD-User. The backend was originally build for a browser-based client and was not meant to serve a mobile.

```
var windowsId = User.Identity as WindowsIdentity;
if (windowsId == null) return null;
var sid = windowsId.User;
```

My idea is to replace the FormsIdentity with a WindowsIdentity after the authentication took place. In order to do this I hook up into the PostAuthenticateRequest event of the ASP.NET pipeline:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class FromToWindowsAuthenticationModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.PostAuthenticateRequest += PostAuthenticateRequest;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        private void PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ctx = HttpContext.Current;
            if (ctx.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var principal = ctx.User;
                var formsIdentity = principal.Identity as FormsIdentity;
                if (formsIdentity != null)
                {
                    var username = formsIdentity.Name;

                    var ident = new WindowsIdentity(...);  // ???????????????????

                    var newUser = new WindowsPrincipal(ident);        
                    ctx.User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal = newUser
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To activate the module these lines have to be added to the Web.Config:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="FormToWindowsAuthenticationModule" 
           type="MyApp.FormToWindowsAuthenticationModule"
           preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

The only thing what is missing is the part that does retrieve the WindowsIdentifier from the ActiveDirectory. How can I do that?

Is my approach feasible at all? Can the replacement of the Identity object interfere with remaining elements of the ASP.NET pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

This looks promising:

```
    private void PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ctx = HttpContext.Current;
        if (ctx.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var principal = ctx.User;
            var formsIdentity = principal.Identity as FormsIdentity;
            if (formsIdentity != null)
            {
                var username = formsIdentity.Name;
                var domain = "mydomain.com";
                var fullyQualifiedUsername = username + "@" + domain;

                var windowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(fullyQualifiedUsername);
                var windowsPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(windowsIdentity);

                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = ctx.User = windowsPrincipal;
            }
        }
    }
```